# Using printf in awk, how to make newline start following the end of old line (for MS-DOS line breaking files)

Tags: awk

I am trying to use Awk to join lines in a file together. Naturally I tried something like

```
awk '{printf (%s), $0}' file.name
```

Yet instead of getting the standard output with everything concatenated into one line. I got only the last line. Then I realised that when performing the printf in each line, my `awk` actually rewrite the old output with the new one.

How to avoid this behaviour? I would like the next line to be written at the end of the existing output. eg.

If the file is

```
abcd abcd abcd
eeffgg ssss
```

The expected output should be

```
abcd abcd abcdeeffgg ssss
```

rather than

```
eeffgg ssssbcd
```

or

```
eeffgg ssss
```

---

To be more specific, I am using OS X, so the awk I used is the unix version, I assume. So the behavior might be different from GNU's `awk`.

---

Further debugging leading to an independent issue. The problem is not caused by unix version of awk. It is caused by MS-DOS style of line breaker in the file.

Since the file I am trying to process was auto-generated by MS-DOS based system. It is using `^M` rather than unix-style line breaker. And this is what causing the issue. Using `sed` to translate the linebreaker solves the issue.

Comment: Sample input and Expected output please ?

Comment: @PS. Done, input and expected output added.

Comment: ` tr -d '\n' <filename` does this help ?

Comment: @PS. tried that, somehow the output is empty...

Comment: `paste -sd' ' filename` should work

Comment: OSX awk is no more `the unix version` than GNU awk or any other awk. It's just OSX awk. You should get GNU awk - OSX awk has some issues that make it harder to work with as you have to keep working around them and GNU awk has a TON of extremely useful extensions, e.g. working just fine with with your data via multi-char RS (`-v RS='\r?\n'`) which OSX awk doesn't support. You say `using sed solves the issue` - why are you adding a sed call when you're already using awk and awk can do anything sed can do? `s/\r//` in sed is just `sub(/\r/,"")`in awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the "`^M`" (or `\r` from `\r\n`) while `printf`ing:

```
awk '{sub(/\r/,""); printf "%s", $0} END {print ""}' file
abcd abcd abcdeeffgg ssss
```

- `sub(/\r/,"")` remove the `\r`
- `printf "%s", $0` output without newline
- `END {print ""}` put a newline in the end of the string

**Addendum:**

There is a comment claiming that the `sub` part is not needed. If I use the example data provided with the question. I'm using gawk in Linux:

```
$ cat > file                       # cat it to a file
abcd abcd abcd
eeffgg ssss
$ unix2dos file                    # convert to DOS enters \r\n
unix2dos: converting file file to DOS format ...
$ file file                        # make sure
file: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$ awk '{printf (%s), $0}' file     # run OP's program
$                                  # there was no visible output due to \r
```

I then proceed to add the `END {print ""}` to OP's program:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s", $0} END {print ""}' file
eeffgg ssssbcd
$                                  # last line is visible due to print "" end END
```

I then add the `sub` part to the program:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\r/,""); printf "%s", $0} END {print ""}' file
abcd abcd abcdeeffgg ssss
$                                  # and we acquire the requested output
```

So I don't feel that the `sub` part is not needed.

Comment: The first part with sub is needless it works as well without it.

Comment: @ClaesWikner I added an example to show why the `sub` part is needed in my approach to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

sample input :

```
cat file.name
abcd abcd abcd
eeffgg ssss
```

Solution using `paste` :

```
paste -sd' ' file.name
abcd abcd abcd eeffgg ssss
```

Solution using `tr`:

```
tr  -d '\n' <file.name
```

Solution using `awk`:  Change `" "` to  `""` ,if you wish. (as per your expected o/p)

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "}{$1=$1}1' file.name
abcd abcd abcd eeffgg ssss
```

Comment: The awk command `awk 'BEGIN{ORS=" "}{$1=$1}1'}' file.name` has an extraneous `}'` at the end of it. It will also convert all chains of white space, including tabs, etc., to single blank characters which isn't something the OP said they wanted.